# run project in xcode 8 after Xcode 9

Tags: xcode

Yesterday I downloaded the XCode 9 and run my project.After working whole day I pushed my code. My colleague  has Xcode 8. He cant update to new version.How to run that code in Xcode 8. Colleague is getting error in compilation (Command failed due to signal segmentation fault:11??

Comment: Did you fix project warnings suggested by Xcode 9?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preference menu in Xcode
tab Locations and change command line tools from xcode9 to xcode8

[image]

Comment: install both version to mac, becouse you also can't compile product version from beta